# iframe looses session on redirection in Chrome

Tags: php, session, iframe

I need a help with a problem I don't know how to fix. The issue I have is the when I nest another pager in iframe and that iframe redirects within it self, it looses the session data.

So the scenario is like this:

- index.php with nested iframe =>

  `<iframe src="http://somedomain/global.php?user=someuser&site=1234567" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0px;"></iframe>`
- global.php file on another domain that creates session and session exists =>

  ```
  $sess_path = '/somepath/';
  session_save_path($sess_path);
  ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user'] = $_GET['user'];
  $_SESSION['site'] = $_GET['site'];
  header('location: ../home.php');
  ```
- within iframe global.php file redirects to home.php and session info is lost

  ```
  $sess_path = '/somepath/';
  $sess_timeout = 30;
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $sess_timeout);
  ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $sess_timeout);
  ini_set('session.cache_expire', $sess_timeout);
  ini_set('session.gc_probability', 100);
  ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
  session_save_path($sess_path);
  ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
  session_start();
  ```
- if I print_r $_SESSION it's empty

I have searched around and found some answers but was unable to make it work (I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding something). First of all my app is based only on Chrome browser and I have found out that chrome now changed something in regards to handling the 3rd part redirections. I have added `ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');` to both global.php and home.php but that made no difference.

If I try my test setup on Firefox it works as intended, so this only makes me to conclude it is something to do with Chrome

Could I ask for some idiot proof instruction on how to fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm that `global.php` and `home.php` are both in the same directory under the same domain? I assume this is true, but you never say this explicitly.

Comment: Yes they are on same domain

Comment: I'm not claiming to have a solution, but I found [this link](https://medium.com/trabe/cookies-and-iframes-f7cca58b3b9e) and in other places I also found that your cookie need to have the attribute `Secure`. I also noted you're using the HTTP protocol instead of the HTTPS protocol. Perhaps that's not a good idea, Google loves HTTPS.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think you are right, after looking at the network tab on DevTools in Chrome it shows error the secure is not enable and the cookie was refused. Do you know any good guide on how to setup https on ubuntu?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have a guide for HTTPS, I use "Let's Encrypt" in "Plesk" and that takes care of everything. Call me lazy.  No idea if this is any help to you: https://letsencrypt.org/docs

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fix my issue by making my website and target website https, now all works fine after adding the two ini settings in global.php:

```
    ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
    ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
```

KIKO Software thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: what if you don't have access to the target site code?

Comment: I do as both are maintained by me.

Comment: That is good for you, but I am looking for a solution where you can share an iframe code so people can put that code in their own websites, so I will not have access to the servers of my clients.